# Attempting a for loop, but I get error mv: cannot stat '' : No such file or directory

Tags: automation, putty

I have wrote this script:

```
for filename in TYP_*; do echo mv \"filename\" \"${filename//TYP/standard.ec}\"; done
```

The outcome is:

```
mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
mv "TYP_5708" "standard.ec5708"
mv "TYP_5709" "standard.ec5709"
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Unrelated to that error, but you'll need `$filename` or `${filename}` for the first use of that variable in that `mv` command you are trying to build.

Comment: Also unrelated to that error, but there are the `mmv` and `rename` commands that both can do that out of the box: `mmv "TYP_*" "standard.ec#1"` or `rename "s/TYP_/standard.ec/" TYP_*` .

Comment: Compare with `ls -1 TYP_*`. The first name there may give a clue; maybe it's plain `TYP_` or `TYP` which might result in an empty name after your search and replace.